# Prove that there is a unit $u \in R$ such that $ub = bu = a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity containing elements $a$ and $b$ with $ab = b$ and $b^2 = a$. Prove that there is a unit $u \in R$ such that $ub = bu = a$.
>
> Source: Problem $15.3.6$, *Algebra in Action: A Course in Groups, Rings, and Fields* by Shahriar Shahriari.

**My work:**

From $ab = b$ and $b^2 = a$, we have $ab^2 = a^2 =  b^2$. So, $a^2 = a$, i.e. $a$ is idempotent. $u = b$ satisfies $ub = bu = a$, but we don't know if $b$ is a unit. I believe the main reason I'm stuck is that $a$ and $b$ may not be units, but from the given information, we likely want to find $u$ in the form $u = a^\alpha b^\beta$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb N$. How do I proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: $a^\alpha b^\beta=a$ or $b$ for every $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Note that $a^\alpha b^\beta$ is either $a$ or $b$. It follows from $a^n = a$ for $n\geq 1$ and $b^{2n} = a^n = a$, $b^{2n+1} = ab = b$.

Comment: That makes sense! So, what is $u$? We don't know (yet) if either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Comment: more precisely, by $ba = b\cdot b^2 = b^2\cdot b = ab$ any product $c$ of $a$s and $b$s (in any order) only depends on the number $\alpha$ of the factors $a$ and the number $\beta$ of the factors $b$. If $\alpha = \beta = 0$, then $c = 1$, if $\beta = 1$, then $c = b$ and in all other cases, $c = a$. But I don't see yet how to proceed. I guess addition and distributivity needs to be brought in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $b^3 = b$ and so $b^4 = b^2$. We may then compute that
$$
(b^2+b-1)^2 = b^4 + 2 b^3 - b^2 - 2 b + 1 = b^2 + 2b - b^2 - 2b + 1 = 1.
$$
Hence $b^2+b-1$ is a unit. Furthermore, we have
$$
(b^2+b-1)b = b(b^2+b-1) = b^3 + b^2 - b = b + b^2 - b = b^2,
$$
so it is the unit we are after.

Comment: Excellent. How did you think of this? What motivated you to look at $b^2 + b - 1$?

Comment: I figured the answer had to be some polynomial in $b$, as there were no other reasonable options. Since $b^3 = b$, it could have been of degree at most 2 and it probably had coefficients $\pm 1$. Then the requirement $ub = b^2$ already forced $u$ to be $b^2+b-1$. Then I tried multiplying some expressions of the form $b^2 \pm b \pm 1$ until the result was 1 to show it is a unit